# How can I download software onto multiple Macs at the same time?

Tags: imac, software

I'm downloading several software on a number of iMacs (all of the same software). I was wondering if there was a way to use a program to be able to download everything simultaneously on all of these different iMacs (17 of them) and configure the same preferences on all of them?

Comment: You may be better off using an MDM in such a scenario.

Comment: In case you are not familiar with the acroymn MDM:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management